# Why my google map resizing is not working, and not centered the map

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, resize, colorbox

I tried to put a google map into a small box first, and when users click a button, it shows a bigger map with full map controller. I use the colorbox to make the effect. The problem is that, when the bigger map shows, there are empty tiles right and down, and the map is not properly centered. 
        `map.setCenter(mapcenter);`
Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/TX94H/2/.
If you need colorbox information, is here:http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Please help, I am desperate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fire the "resize" event on your map :

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

To ensure the resize is happening once the map is displayed, I used this :

```
setTimeout('google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");', 500);
```

There is probably a better way, you should check if your colorbox library is firing an event AFTER the box is shown (please see my comment below, i found the solution).

Check it out:

[Demo on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TX94H/3/)

Comment: After checking the library documentation, it seems that instead of a timeout, you should use 'onComplete' event instead of the 'onOpen' : http://jsfiddle.net/TX94H/4/